# How can i add the remarks column with comma separated? select query mess

Tags: php, mysql, select, pivot

I have 3 pairs of in/out employee records existing code..
but from the my table I need the remarks on each and every input be seen in one cell with comma separated.

Please see my fiddle.. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/afe72/1/0

My table will be like this..

```
create table overallrec(
    td_id int auto_increment primary key,
    emp_id int,  
    status varchar(3),
    timestamp datetime,
    remarks varchar(255)
);

insert into overallrec(emp_id,status,timestamp) values  
 ( 35, 'in' , '2013-12-19 10:15:09', 'late'),
 ( 35, 'out', '2013-12-19 12:00:23', 'example'),
 ( 35, 'in' , '2013-12-19 13:00:23'),
 ( 35, 'out', '2013-12-19 16:01:47'),
 ( 35, 'in' , '2013-12-19 18:01:17'),
 ( 35, 'out', '2013-12-19 22:01:07'),
 ( 35, 'in' , '2013-12-20 10:00:12'),
 ( 36, 'in' , '2013-12-18 10:15:09'),
 ( 36, 'out', '2013-12-18 12:00:23'),
 ( 37, 'in' , '2013-12-17 10:15:09'),
 ( 37, 'out', '2013-12-17 12:00:23'),
 ( 37, 'in' , '2013-12-17 13:00:23');
```

I want it to have a remarks at the end of each row with a comma separated strings.
like this(reference 1st row from my fiddle):

```
35  in  December, 19 2013 10:15:09+0000
out December, 19 2013 12:00:23+0000
in  December, 19 2013 13:00:23+0000
out December, 19 2013 16:01:47+0000
in  December, 19 2013 18:01:17+0000
out December, 19 2013 22:01:07+0000      late, example
```

Please help me.. I'm hoping for an answer as a Christmas gift.. :/

Answer (score 0):

GROUP_CONCAT can probably give you what you need.

Try this query to give you one resultset row per day per employee.

```
SELECT emp_id,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(status, ' ', timestamp)) AS log,
       GROUP_CONCAT(remarks) AS remarks
  FROM overallrec
 GROUP BY emp_id, DATE_FORMAT(timestamp,'%Y-%m-%d')
 ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(timestamp,'%Y-%m-%d'), emp_id
```

I didn't format your timestamps the same way you did, but other than that I think this is close.  Here's a fiddle. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d7755/5/0

Answer (score 0):

Well this, but you can't possilby maintain this easily http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c16169/2/0

Comment: It doesn't read the fifth out remarks sir.. and when a remark row is empty it generates unnecessary comma..  But your code is super nice sir.. there is only a little glitch

Comment: Sir can u make a view out of your code sir?... I highly appreciate your mastery sir..  pleeeeeeeaaaaaaaase?....

Comment: @user3117337, are you user3114385 as well? if so log into your other account and look up the question where I gave you a view, I updated with another sqlFiddle with remarks in a view.